# Javascript library for drawing block diagrams

Tags: javascript, highcharts, uml, diagram

Simple question:

I would like to draw block diagrams as for example here: 
http://psychedelic-information-theory.com/control-theory-chart

And I am looking for a nice javascript library doing that for me.

Currently I am using highcharts however I think highcharts is not made for that.

Does anyone of you draw block diagrams and knows a nice js library doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Cytscape](http://js.cytoscape.org/) is another one that could do the job but I guess you're looking something like [JointJS](http://resources.jointjs.com/). JointJS used to offer also free version although now quickly looking it seems to be more or less commercial. I did some experiments with it few years back and it had pretty nice API.